# How to connect to Wifi Network with i3wm?

Tags: networking, network-manager, i3-wm

I just installed Ubuntu minimal with i3wm, but I can't figure out, how to connect it to the wireless network.

I already have installed network-manager package. Also  I added `exec --no-startup-id nm-applet` to my ~/.config/i3 but apt-get cannot find network-manager-applet to install.

Im stuck here, what can I do?

Comment: make sure that you have nm-applet installed running: `apt install network-manager`

Answer (score 31):

I use (and would recommend) [`nmtui`](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmtui.html), a curses based TUI that will allow you to edit and activate connections.

It should already be installed on your system, but if not, you can get it by running `sudo apt install network-manager`.

Comment: Is it possible to set it connect to wifi when log in using i3?

Answer (score 17):

You can use Network Manager's command line tool called `nmcli`.


1. Use `nmcli dev wifi` to locate the access point(AP) name.

2. Use `nmcli device wifi connect APname password password`

Comment: Not sure about ubuntu, but on Fedora, this is the best option as it doesn't require installing anything and if you can't do something from the cli, you should learn how.

Answer (score 6):

Use dmenu (`$mod+d` by default) and type `gnome-control-center` then **Network → Wireless**.

On some older Ubuntu versions you'll need to do `unity-control-center` instead.

Comment: this should be the easiest option

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have NetworkManager, install it:

```
$: sudo apt -y install network-manager-gnome
```

Set up your connection:

```
$: nm-connection-editor
```

This way your connection will be persistent on restart.

Answer (score 0):

I think the applet should be in the network-manager-gnome package. If you don't have it run:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

Also make sure the network manager service is running. You can check with:

```
systemctl list-units NetworkManager.service
```

If it's not loaded you should either start it with:

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

or enable so it will also be there after restarting with:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i did have the network-manager-gnome installed, but the i3 status bar doesnt show any icon, also im having the same problem with dropbox. Any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try running nm-applet from a terminal to see if gives any errors?

Comment: nm-applet doesnt give any error or message when i run it from the console, what can it be?

Comment: To be honest I don't really know either at this point. You could try connecting to a network through the command line to see if the problem lies with NetworkManager or the applet. Check out instructions here [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Command_line). Or maybe the problem is with the i3 tray, check out the user guide for it here [link](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_tray_output)

Comment: I connected to the network via the command line, i cant fix the tray problem with i3, no idea what can it be. Thanks a lot for your help.